# On Linux, how can I tell how many ephemeral ports are left available?

Tags: linux, port

Is there a method in Linux to check how many ephemeral ports are left available? I occasionally see "Address already in use" errors as a result of running out of ephemeral ports. A machine reboot will resolve this but it would be better to catch it before it happens.

Comment: If you are hitting errors like that I would suggest that either you are either abusing the system by not using the right software or architecture for a job, or your software is misbehaving or misconfigured. Perhaps your timeouts are too long for your application or something is leaving connections open without using them?

Comment: There are many valid applications that require additional ephemeral ports beyond OS defaults.

Answer (score 34):

The ephermal port range is specified in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. You can probably extend it to run from 16k to 64k.

You can see the number of open connections using `netstat -an`. Sockets may be stuck in TIME_WAIT state if you are opening and closing a lot of connections. In some places this is unavoidable, but you may need to consider if you need a pool of connection if this is the case.

If TIME_WAIT is the problem, you can set `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` / `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle` to speed up connection turnover.

Comment: +1, thanks for taking the time to give this guy exact details.

Comment: We have a range of 32800 to 61000. We just find that once these have been used the OS will not use them again. This is expected behaviour, but I would expect the OS to start again at the beginning once it reaches the last available port. This doesn't seem to happen though. Also, just to note, this isn't a hugely regular occurance. It is intermittent but we do have a large number of servers.

Comment: Note that [`net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle` was removed in Linux  4.12](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4396e46187ca5070219b81773c4e65088dac50cc)

Comment: To comply with [RFC 6335](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6335) `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` needs to be a subset of 49152-65535. So reducing the lower end of the range to anything less than 49152 does come at a certain risk.

Comment: never user net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle nor net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse except if you're desperate and know exactly what you're doing. You're exposing your service to potential extrems issue.

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that this limit applies per unique (source IP, peer IP, peer port) tuple. Therefore you will need to group the output of `netstat`/`ss` by each of these tuples, and check how close each group is to the connection limit.

[This post](https://making.pusher.com/ephemeral-port-exhaustion-and-how-to-avoid-it/) explains how you can do this grouping in more detail. To check how close each group is to the limit in Ruby, you can process `ss` output like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

first_port, last_port = IO.read('/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range').split.map(&:to_i)
ephemeral_port_max = last_port - first_port + 1
ephemeral_port_warning = ephemeral_port_max / 3 * 2

conns = `ss --numeric --tcp state connected "( sport >= :#{first_port} and sport <= :#{last_port} )"`

groups = Hash.new(0)
conns.lines.each do |conn|
  state, recvq, sendq, local, peer = conn.split
  local_ip, local_port = local.split(':')
  group = [local_ip, peer]
  groups[group] += 1
end

groups_requiring_warning =
  groups.select { |k, v| v > ephemeral_port_warning }
  .to_a
  .sort_by { |v1, v2| v1[1] <=> v2[1] } # Sort groups in descending order of number of connections

groups_requiring_warning.each do |group, used_port_count|
  puts "Connections from #{group[0]} to #{group[1]} "\
    "have used #{used_port_count} ephemeral ports out of #{ephemeral_port_max} max"\
    "(#{((used_port_count.to_f / ephemeral_port_max) * 100).round(2)}% used)"
end
```